# I am getting red lines under my flutter code but the code is perfectly functioning and there is no error

Tags: android-studio, flutter

As you can see on the top right side, there is a green tick meaning the code is working and the app I built using this functioning perfectly and as expected.
Need help getting ride of those red underlines.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJvvJ.png

Update 1:[Output of flutter doctor -v](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAOPB.png)
Update 2:[Output of debug on app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yhl1.png)

Comment: Did you install the Flutter plugin?

Comment: post output of `flutter doctor -v` command

Comment: @Thepeanut Yes, I have

Comment: @pskink As you can see there is no error in flutter doctor -v

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, it was very frustrating but was able to solve it.

What worked for me was restoring my Android Studio setting to the default settings by removing the entire "`.AndroidStudio4.0`" (or whatever version you are using) folder that is usually located in `C:\Users\[user name]\.`

Then you open Android Studio, select `NOT to import any settings`, install the Dart and Flutter plugins, and that's it.

It should take about 2 minutes.

Comment: Thank you. Thank you so much. I have been looking for this for more than 3 months. You are a literal GOD

Comment: Invalidate cache and restart solved the same for me

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to stack overflow. Looks like a standard package import error.

See link here. https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages

I suggest you try in terminal running three commands

```
flutter doctor
flutter clean 
flutter pub get
```

If you see errors at any of these commands, act accordingly.

If no error, I suggest check the contents of your .packages file and pubspec.lock that they list all the dependencies you want to import including Flutter and Dart.

Comment: Yes, there is no error and all the required dependencies are there.

Answer (score 1):

```
flutter doctor
flutter clean 
flutter pub get
```

after entering these commands flutter code doesn't compile.

I tried **`flutter upgrade`** and now problem got solved.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using VS Code, sometimes restarting your analyzer solves your problem. sometimes `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub get` solves.
in my case, both are not working.
This issue is having with only one project, are projects are still working fine.
I think Reinstallng Android Studio and Flutter sdk will solve this

Comment: how to restart the analyzer ?

Answer (score 0):

Look at your first import, it should be something like this:

```
'package:YOURAPPNAME/FadeAnimation.dart'
```

Also, try to invalidate android studio cache and restart (in file menu)

Comment: Did both, no difference

Comment: what do you get in your debug log when you try to launch the app?

Comment: I have put up the screenshot

Comment: Maybe try to reload your project (cut it and paste it in an other folder and then reload it), or try to remove the latest line of code you have added.

Answer (score 0):

Use flutter upgrade command this helped me.

Answer (score 0):

After weeks try to figure out the problem and try all the suggestions (not working in my case), I noticed that my project's Flutter SDK path is empty. After I enter the correct path, all the red line disappear instantly!

Steps:

1. Go to File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Flutter.
2. Flutter SDK path: C:\src\flutter (in my case)
3. Click Apply
4. Click OK

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your `Fadeanimation` file make it `fadeanimation` the capital word is effect your code.